# Sharepoint popup login windows

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, popup

After I log into my sharepoint website, I have to login everytime I access a document from the library. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? FBA?

Comment: Is the prompt from Internet Explorer or from the application opening the document?

Answer (score 11):

User Level:

If your SharePoint site always prompts for username/password on accessing it you can set your browser to not prompt

1. In Internet Explorer, go to Tools
2. Click Internet Options
3. add your site URL to Internet Explorers "Local Intranet Sites" section.
4. Open Security tab
5. Click Custom Level button
6. Scroll down to this screen and select "Automatic logon with current username and password" radio button
7. Click OK.

Administrator Level:

you can add your site's internal zone URL in **Alternate Access Mappings** section on **Central Administration>Operations** site,  The SharePoint server always does not prompt for username/password and you can enjoy.

Comment: I wish I could give 10 points for this question/answer. This has been quite irritating for months.

Comment: is there a way to do it without making changes in the IE settings? 
Will it work if we make just the administrator level change?

Answer (score 6):

When using Windows Vista or Windows 7 the office tools (e.g. Word) do not look at the Local Intranet list of Internet Explorer. But they look at the following registry location:

**HKEY__LOCAL__MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\AuthForwardServerList**

If your sharepoint site is located at share.myserver.com you can set the above registry entry to ***.myserver.com** (including the *) so that all addresses ending with myserver.com are trusted by the office applications. This will prevent the login popup box from appearing.

For more info see [this microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/943280). It solved the problem for me.

Comment: I searched forever for this solution, but this fixed my problems on Windows 7 with mapped libraries and sites not connecting on startup!

Answer (score 1):

Add the SharePoint site to your trusted sites or local intranet in Internet Options.

Comment: What browser are you using? I think only IE will be able to pass your credentials off to Word or Excel...

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. I've added it to trusted sites and made sure it has the "Automatic logon with current user name and password" option. It still asks for it. This is IE.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with the way Word does the request for a file It sends an anonymous request first. What solves this is setting the session cookie to be valid for a year.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AD for the Authentication ?
Are you browsing the site from same network where it is hosted or on a Different N/W ?

If in the Same new work "Add the SharePoint site to your trusted sites or local intranet in Internet Options" and in the Trusted Sites Security Custom Level , User Authentication Section  select the Option Automatically Login with the Current User Name and Password.

If you are browsing from Different n/w its bit tough to get it .

Answer (score 0):

I experience this every day. My local machine is on a different domain to the SharePoint server so I have to log in every time I access SharePoint with a different application. This includes IE, Word, InfoPath, etc...

There is no way I've found to avoid it as it's simply part of using Windows authentication. Saving your password can help but still shows a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that could cause this and you don't give much detail on your setup in the Q to give you an answer but...

The most comprehensive article I've found for troubleshooting this is

[Unwanted Authentication Prompts](http://blogs.msdn.com/danielmcpherson/archive/2006/02/16/533605.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is familiar to me and I've previously used the upvoted solution to the problem. However, recently I discovered that using Google Chrome rather than Internet Explorer makes this problem go away!

Solution: Use Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Switching to Basic Authentication will resolve this issue at a cost of passing credentials in clear text.